# Navigate to a different Navigator using reset action in react navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

My current structure is

```
const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator({
AuthLoading,
MainNavigator,
AuthNavigator
},
{
 initialRouteName: 'AuthLoading'
});
```

AuthNavigator

```
const OtpVerificationStack = createSwitchNavigator({
OTPLoading,
SignupNavigator,
MainNavigator
},
{
initialRouteName: 'OTPLoading',
});

const AuthNavigator = createStackNavigator({
VerificationNavigator,
OtpVerificationStack
},
{
initialRouteName: 'VerificationNavigator',
header: null,
headerMode: 'none'
 });
```

VerificationNavigator

```
const VerificationNavigator = createStackNavigator({
MobileNo,
OTPVer
},
{
header: null,
headerMode: 'none'
});
```

When I register user i.e. from AuthNavigator -> VerificationNavigator(after otpver screen to otpverificationStack) -> OTPVerificationStack -> SignupNavigator(screen 1) there is a google login option here, so when someone logs in using this I need to reset route to MainNavigator.
I tried kee[ing key null, or MainNavigator while dispatching a resetAction but it returns undefined route error.

Comment: did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826920/how-to-navigate-between-different-nested-stacks-in-react-navigation you can add a reset action to the answer in this post. You'd just pass the name of the other stack you are trying to navigate

Comment: @kivul I tried keeping key as OTPVerificationStack and routeName as MainNavigator. Keeping the key as a stacknavigator, I had to pass routeName as a navigator too. It seems that does not work.

Comment: I am curious to know why you would like to have `VerificationNavigator` as a separate stack navigator? Instead you can make use of those screens in AuthNavigator itself.

Comment: Also why reset, when you can navigate to `MainNavigator `?

Comment: @10101010 I need to verify user with OTP. If the user exists I just get user data and go to MainNavigator else I continue with signup, hence. Also If I do that, when the user presses the back button in the phone it goes back to the old screen.