# No route found for key in stack navigator in react native

Tags: react-native

I am making a react native project which got an error for no route found in stack navigator.First of all here is my code for navigation of my app.

```
const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
  Splash : { screen: Splash },
  ModelProfile: { screen: ModelProfile},
  HomeModel: {screen: modeldrawerNavigator},
  EnterOtp : { screen: EnterOtp},
  OtpChangePassword : { screen: OtpChangePassword},
}, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Splash'
})

const AppNavigator = createAppContainer(RootStack)
export default AppNavigator;
```

Now the code for `modelDrawerNavigator` is

```
const modeldrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
  {
    HomeScreen: { screen: homeStack},
    EditProfile : { screen: profileStack},
    BuyStar : { screen: StarStack},
    Notifications : { screen: nStackmodel},
    ResetPassword : { screen: ResetPassword},
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'HomeScreen',
    gesturesEnabled: true,
    contentComponent: props => <DrawerModel {...props} />
  },
);
```

And code for `StarStack` is

```
const StarStack = createStackNavigator({
  Buy : { screen: BuyStars},
  PaymentMode : { screen: PaymentMode},
 }, {
  headerMode: 'none',
  initialRouteName: 'Buy'
 });
```

Now when navigating inside drawer i want to clear stack to position 0.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  onPress={() => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('BuyStar');
    const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
      index: 0,
      actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Buy' })],
    });
    this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
  }}
>
  <Text style={styles.drawertext}>Buy Stars</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Above code is what produces an error that

`No route defined for key 'Buy',Must be one of 'Splash','EnterOtp' etc.`

I am stuck in this situation . Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance .

Comment: That last bit with the `TouchableOpacity` is in the `BuyStars` component, correct? Mind sharing the rest of the code for it?

Comment: Yes BuyStars is a label on a drawer which takes to that screen.And also BuyStars is component which is in stack with key Buy

Comment: Which part of code you want ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the issue is your code is attempting to navigate the root navigator (`Splash` and `EnterOp` are both keys on this navigator).  According to the [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-actions.html):

> key - string or null - optional - If set, the navigator with the given key will reset. If null, the root navigator will reset.

So maybe you can try adding the `key` param to your `reset` action:

```
const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: 'Buy' })],
  key: 'BuyStar',
});
```

Here are some more resources that may help:

[SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826920/how-to-navigate-between-different-nested-stacks-in-react-navigation)

[Github Issue](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/1979)

Note that the implementation will likely depend on if you're using React Navigation 3.0+ or one of the earlier versions.

**EDIT**

The supplied key should be `BuyStar` - you're trying to navigate to the route `Buy`, which exists in the `StarStack` navigator.  The `StarStack` navigator is located in the drawer navigator, so the key of this navigator is found in its keys:

```
const modeldrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  ...
  BuyStar : { screen: StarStack },
  ...
```

The key should be the id of the navigator that contains the route you're trying to navigate to.

Comment: How can BuyStar be key if this  belongs to a key of drawernavigator ?