# How can i open another Screen using a button ReactNative

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-drawer

Let me explain properly what I want to do.

I have these screens in react-native mobile-app

App.js

WalletDetails.js

Then I have another screen called PaymentDetails.js amongst many other screens

So what I want to do is that I need a button with `onPress` that would open directly walletDetails.js screen from PaymentDetails.js.

I have this code already on the paymentdetails page

```
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.cardPayBtn} onPress={()=>props.navigation.navigate("WalletDetails"); }}> <Text style={styles.buttonTitle}>{userdata && userdata.usertype == 'rider' ? t('payWithCard') : t('request_payment')}</Text> </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: what is screen referred to in the question?

Comment: @Beginner Navigation. I've several app pages. There's a page where payment is made and I want a button there that can take users to my wallet page as attached in this image link  https://ibb.co/vCNGfKW

By screen I'm trying to say pages or views in react native

Comment: Sorry, I thought It was reactJS. You should add a react-native tag to your question.

Comment: I'm sorry about that too. It is react native. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to navigate between different nested stacks in react navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49826920/how-to-navigate-between-different-nested-stacks-in-react-navigation)

Answer (score 0):

I think for navigating between screens, React recomments react-navigation, it's a module to handle multiple screens (I'm using it myself and I really like it).

To get started, the [react-navigation getting-started-guide](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/getting-started) helps a lot!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can use for this navigation purpose between one screen to another.

```
onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("WalletDetails")
```